# vmware fusion view coldfusion debugging host os

Tags: apache, debugging, coldfusion, localhost, vmware-workstation

i am using vmware fusion windows xp apache coldfusion 8 and I am trying to view the cf debugging through safari on my snow leopard host.  I have turned on debugging and tried adding my ip, however, this did not work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you trying to access the debug outside of vmware or inside of vmware? If outside, make sure you are adding the IP of your mac machine, not the vmware machine.  Also, you might have to make sure your networking for vmware is bridged so they have different IP addresses (vmware may not call it bridged, im not sure).

The easiest way to do this is access the cf administrator from outside of the vm on the mac machine and set it that way.  Also make sure that the coldfusion page you are running doesn't have debugging supressed.

Comment: thanks man, i set it up as bridged and i removed the 127.0.0.1 from the cfm debugging ips, so it shows for all ips and it worked great